# Terraform deletes old AWS Lambda Layer version instead of creating new

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created a AWS Lambda Layer and created terraform code which deploys it to AWS. I want it that everytime I create new version of layer it is deployed as a new version without deleting the old one. However right now it does the opposite and just adds new version but deletes the old one. How to change it ?

Here is my terraform code

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object_lambda_common_layer" {
  bucket = "tm-bamboo-deploys"
  key = "lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer/lambda_common_layer_${data.archive_file.layer_zip_lambda_common_layer.output_base64sha256}.zip"
  source = "${data.archive_file.layer_zip_lambda_common_layer.output_path}"
  etag = "${data.archive_file.layer_zip_lambda_common_layer.output_md5}"
  depends_on = [
    "data.archive_file.layer_zip_lambda_common_layer"]
}

data "archive_file" "layer_zip_lambda_common_layer" {
  type = "zip"
  source_dir = "../../src"
  output_path = "../../lambda_common_layer.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "lambda_common_layer" {
  layer_name = "lambda_common_layer"
  s3_bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.bucket}"
  s3_key = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.key}"
  s3_object_version = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.version_id}"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.layer_zip_lambda_common_layer.output_base64sha256}"
  description = "Common layer providing logging"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.6"]
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "tfstate-dev-tm"
    region         = "eu-central-1"
    key            = "service/lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer.tfenv"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform_locks"
  }
}
```

Terraform plan

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.archive_file.layer_zip_lambda_common_layer: Refreshing state...
aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer: Refreshing state... (ID: lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer/lambda_common_layer.zip)
aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_common_layer: Refreshing state... (ID: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:layer:lambda_common_layer:12)

------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

-/+ aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_common_layer (new resource required)
      id:                             "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:layer:lambda_common_layer:12" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      arn:                            "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:layer:lambda_common_layer" => <computed>
      compatible_runtimes.#:          "1" => "1"
      compatible_runtimes.4000986591: "python3.6" => "python3.6"
      created_date:                   "2019-02-12T11:09:19.948+0000" => <computed>
      description:                    "Common layer providing logging" => "Common layer providing logging"
      layer_arn:                      "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:layer:lambda_common_layer:12" => <computed>
      layer_name:                     "lambda_common_layer" => "lambda_common_layer"
      s3_bucket:                      "tm-bamboo-deploys" => "tm-bamboo-deploys"
      s3_key:                         "lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer/lambda_common_layer.zip" => "lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer/lambda_common_layer_tjn78HvsQ6vIUKxcXg+jnawPvwxyCgflesbNwz8o1Xc=.zip" (forces new resource)
      s3_object_version:              "" => "${aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.version_id}" (forces new resource)
      source_code_hash:               "tjn78HvsQ6vIUKxcXg+jnawPvwxyCgflesbNwz8o1Xc=" => "tjn78HvsQ6vIUKxcXg+jnawPvwxyCgflesbNwz8o1Xc="
      source_code_size:               "350" => <computed>
      version:                        "12" => <computed>

-/+ aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer (new resource required)
      id:                             "lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer/lambda_common_layer.zip" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      acl:                            "private" => "private"
      bucket:                         "tm-bamboo-deploys" => "tm-bamboo-deploys"
      content_type:                   "binary/octet-stream" => <computed>
      etag:                           "d14b146b3478f1cdfa0dee3ada2fe79c" => "484a7fe7ce87c8c88ca5bf038b6bd426"
      key:                            "lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer/lambda_common_layer.zip" => "lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer/lambda_common_layer_tjn78HvsQ6vIUKxcXg+jnawPvwxyCgflesbNwz8o1Xc=.zip" (forces new resource)
      server_side_encryption:         "" => <computed>
      source:                         "../../lambda_common_layer.zip" => "../../lambda_common_layer.zip"
      storage_class:                  "STANDARD" => <computed>
      version_id:                     "" => <computed>


Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 2 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.
```

Comment: Can you share the output from a plan?

Comment: yes please, I added to the post

Comment: I don't know if you've seen that @ClydeBarrow, but there is ongoing ticket for that problem on Terraform repo: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7552. There is a PR waiting https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/11997 as well. Maybe you could encourage author to finish the change? :]

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behavior of terraform. It keeps track of the state and module. If it see any change that requires force recreate from the provider, it destroys the old one and creates a new one.

If you want to keep the old one, create a new one also, one thing i can suggest as you are using dynamoDb and S3 bucket to maintain your tfstate is to change `key` in your terraform block and then manually maintain the versions of all the lambda layer you have created. In future if you want to destroy any version, just use the key you used to create that lambda layer and run `terraform destroy`.

So example :
1st time your use this :

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "tfstate-dev-tm"
    region         = "eu-central-1"
    key            = "service/lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer_v1.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform_locks"
  }
}
```

Then 2nd time when you want to create a new lambda layer change the terraform to :

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "tfstate-dev-tm"
    region         = "eu-central-1"
    key            = "service/lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer_v2.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform_locks"
  }
}
```

Now, it will create a new lambda layer. Once you want to delete your old lambda layer, you can do again this :

```
terraform {
      backend "s3" {
        bucket         = "tfstate-dev-tm"
        region         = "eu-central-1"
        key            = "service/lambda/layers/lambda_common_layer_v1.tfstate"
        dynamodb_table = "terraform_locks"
      }
    }
```

and run `terraform destroy` and it will delete your old lambda layer.

Only problem with this I see is if you change your core module which actually provision your resource, then it might create an issue when you are actually destroy an old version of lambda layer. If possible, you can try copying the terraform and assign version to actual terraform file instead of terraform backend key, so you can destroy that response later without any issue as you would have the original terraform file version, through which it was actually created. Hope this helps.

Comment: well unfortunately it does not help we want to keep everything automated, to be done by CI

Comment: Maybe you can track this issue then : https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15485

Comment: Have a look here : https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html. Maybe you can use this command to run from your CI to remove your state dat from terraform state file after each successful `terraform apply`. Only issue will be you wont be able to manage your resource with terraform anymore like `terraform destroy` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The `aws_lambda_layer_version` resource now has (as of AWS provider v3.66.0) a [`skip_destroy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_layer_version#skip_destroy) argument to skip deletion when the layer version changes. If you set `skip_destroy = true` and make a change to the layer version, a new version will be published but the old one will not be deleted. In other words, you'll still have both the old *and* new layer versions. That seems to resolve your problem?

This is how you would use it:

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "lambda_common_layer" {
  layer_name          = "lambda_common_layer"
  skip_destroy        = true
  s3_bucket           = aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.bucket
  s3_key              = aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.key
  s3_object_version   = aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.version_id
  source_code_hash    = data.archive_file.layer_zip_lambda_common_layer.output_base64sha256
  description         = "Common layer providing logging"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.6"]
}
```

NOTE: If you use `skip_destroy = true`, you are responsible to delete layer versions on your own. According to the note, `terraform destroy` will not get rid of your layers.